# Xcode build fails for react-native AwesomeProject

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm running `Xcode 4.6.3` on `OS X 10.7.5`. I've set the iOS Deployment Target to 6.1 in Xcode and selected the iPhone 6.1 simulator. When I hit Run the React Packager appears and says it is ready.

Xcode then fails to build with four parse errors related to RCTImageDownloader.m and there are also nine Target Integrity warnings:

> `/Users/SM/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/AdSupport/RCTAdSupport.xcodeproj`
> iOS Deployment Target `7.0` is newer than SDK `iOS 6.1` in target
> RCTAdSupport

What are my options for resolving this problem?

Comment: Are you able to upgrade Xcode? I'm not sure what the minimum version is for RN but you are quite outdated.

Comment: It would be nice to know what the minimum Xcode version for RN is, have not seen that anywhere. I could update Xcode BUT I'd also need to update my OS and I'd like to avoid that. I'm looking to confirm the severity of my dilemma :]

Answer (score 0):

The tools do not support building for a newer deployment target than the SDK supports.  You need to lower the deployment target from 7.0 to 6.1 or use newer tools (which will require a newer version of OSX as well).

Comment: The way I understood it after reading many issues was that the baseline for RN is SDK 7.0. This would mean that the Xcode version I have is out of date but it is the last one that will run on my MBP with OS Lion. So, I've spent a day doing extensive backups and decided that Mavericks was the better OS for my machine, only to learn that Yosemite is all that is offered at the Mac App Store. Hopefully I can get that all resolved by tomorrow! If it is really possible to work with the system I presently have then please do confirm that, thank-you.

Comment: If you purchased Macericks, it should still be available for download in the purchases tab.  If you didn't, you may have missed out.