# Xcode build error for react-native

Tags: xcode, react-native

maybe the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320153/xcode-build-fails-for-react-native-awesomeproject)
, I follow [official website tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) workflow and try to build AwesomeProject, but even I choose different version, problem still exist

I can't describe clearly and directly screenshot below

[image: error log]

certainly I installed react-native by following official guide step

```
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
$ react-native init AwesomeProject
```

could anybody help me out of this error, thx ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out where `react-native` is installed, using `which react-native`, then change the reference to `react-native`, within the script called by Xcode, to `/full/path/to/react-native`.

Harder way: Modify the `$PATH` that Xcode uses so it looks in the new path.  I wouldn't do this as it's hassle and appears to change with every version of OSX.  I think it's done by editing `/etc/paths` and restarting; not sure though.

Comment: I find bin place here `/Users/Jovi/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin/react-native`, but I don't know how to add this path to Xcode's script  : (